# Issue converting video to live photo to wallpaper

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, photosframework, phlivephoto

I'm using [this](https://github.com/mzp/LoveLiver) way of converting a video + image to live photo. It adds the needed metadata to the video and still image. It exports the new video with the correct metadata using `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` so the codec settings shouldn't be changed.

After I set the output high resolution live photo as wallpaper on my phone's home screen, the quality is greatly reduced and pixelated.

This does not happen, or at least not to the same extent, when setting a photo taken from the camera as live wallpaper.

Anyone have any idea on what could be the issue?

Comment: Can you please provide us some code so we can help you better?